# Facebook Graph API events not returning upcoming events

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to return a list of upcoming events from the Facebook Graph API that are upcoming events that I have not created or RSVP'd to. Right now I can only return a list of events that I have created myself or events I have RSVP'd to. On my facebook's event page I can see other events that are upcoming but do not get returned in my api call.

`me/events` returns just the RSVP'd events

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Search API to find public events you did not RSVP to: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#search

You can only search by name though. It is not possible to list the events from your event page, if you did not RSPV to them. It´s a suggestion list that only Facebook offers on facebook.com.

Comment: Thanks luschn yea the upcoming events was what I was after I didn't know that was a suggested list by Facebook. I tried the public event list by using the search but it only gave me 1 event in 2016 which is odd because I have a bunch of them in my upcoming events page on my facebook account created by my friends.

Comment: you can search events by name in general, not just your own ones or your own suggestions. not sure how reliable it is though.